# I keep getting a tk#2 window showing up and I'm not sure why

Tags: python, tkinter

Whenever I press OK on the login success window I get the window that I intend to show up however I also get a blank window with the title "tk #2" and im not sure why.

This is login.py

```
from tkinter import *
import os
from main import session

def registerUser():
    usernameInfo = username.get()
    passwordInfo = password.get()
    file=open(usernameInfo, "w")
    file.write(usernameInfo + "\n")
    file.write(passwordInfo)
    file.close()
    usernameEntry.delete(0, END)
    passwordEntry.delete(0, END)
    Label(screen1, text = "Registration Sucessful", fg = "green", font = ("Calibri", 11)).pack()

def loginVerify():
    username1 = usernameVerify.get()
    password1 = passwordVerify.get()
    usernameEntry1.delete(0, END)
    passwordEntry1.delete(0, END)
    listofFiles = os.listdir()
    if username1 in listofFiles:
        file1 = open(username1, "r")
        verify = file1.read().splitlines()
        if password1 in verify:
            loginSucess()
        else:
            incorrectPassword()
    else:
        userNotFound()

def register():
    global screen1
    global username
    global password
    global usernameEntry
    global passwordEntry

    screen1 = Toplevel(screen)
    screen1.title("Register")
    screen1.geometry("300x250")
    username = StringVar()
    password = StringVar()
    Label(screen1, text = "Please enter details below: ").pack()
    Label(screen1, text = "").pack()
    Label(screen1, text = "Username *").pack()
    usernameEntry = Entry(screen1, textvariable = username)
    usernameEntry.pack()
    Label(screen1, text = "Password *").pack()
    passwordEntry = Entry(screen1, textvariable = password)
    passwordEntry.pack()
    Label(screen1, text = "").pack()
    Button(screen1, text = "Register", width = "10", height = "1", command = registerUser).pack()

def delete2():
    screen3.destroy()

def loginSucess():
    global screen3
    screen3 = Toplevel(screen)
    screen3.title("Success")
    screen3.geometry("250x100")
    Label(screen3, text = "Login Success").pack()
    Button(screen3, text = "OK", command = lambda: [delete2(), session()]).pack()

def incorrectPassword():
    global screen3
    screen3 = Toplevel(screen)
    screen3.title("Incorrect Password")
    screen3.geometry("250x200")
    Label(screen3, text = "Sorry, the password you've\nentered is incorrect,\nPlease try again").pack()
    Button(screen3, text = "OK", command = delete2).pack()

def userNotFound():
    global screen3
    screen3 = Toplevel(screen)
    screen3.title("User Not Found")
    screen3.geometry("250x200")
    Label(screen3, text = "Sorry, the username you've entered\nhasn't been found,\nPlease try again").pack()
    Button(screen3, text = "OK", command = delete2).pack()

def login():
    global screen2
    global usernameVerify
    global passwordVerify
    global usernameEntry1
    global passwordEntry1

    screen2 = Toplevel(screen)
    screen2.title("Login")
    screen2.geometry("500x250")
    Label(screen2, text = "Please enter details below to login: ").pack()
    Label(screen2, text = "").pack()

    usernameVerify = StringVar()
    passwordVerify = StringVar()

    Label(screen2, text = "Username *").pack()
    usernameEntry1 = Entry(screen2, textvariable = usernameVerify)
    usernameEntry1.pack()
    Label(screen2, text = "").pack()
    Label(screen2, text = "Password *").pack()
    passwordEntry1 = Entry(screen2, textvariable = passwordVerify)
    passwordEntry1.pack()

    Label(screen2, text = "").pack()
    Button(screen2, text = "Login", width = "10", height = "1", command = loginVerify).pack()


def mainScreen():
    global screen
    screen = Tk()
    screen.geometry("300x250")
    screen.title("User Login")
    Label(text = "Please Login Below", bg = "grey", width = "300", height = "2", font = ("Calibri", 13)).pack()
    Label(text = "").pack()
    Button(text = "Login", width = "30", height = "2", command = login).pack()
    Label(text = "").pack()
    Button(text = "Register", width = "30", height = "2", command = register).pack()
    screen.mainloop()

mainScreen()
```

This is main.py

```
from tkinter import *
import login
def session():
    global screen
    screen = Tk()
    screen4 = Toplevel(screen)
    screen4.title("Dashboard")
    screen4.geometry("400x400")
    Label(screen4, text = "Welcome to the Dashboard").pack()
```

Then once I run the `main.py` this is the extra window that pops up:

[image: screenshot]

I have no clue what I'm doing.

Comment: The extra window is created by the line `screen = Tk()` inside `session()`.

Comment: Forgot to say it at the time but thanks :) you fixed it